# What's the name of the property that $a \cdot (b / c) = (a \cdot b) / c?$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there a name for this property?

$$a \cdot (b/c) = (a \cdot b) / c$$

It's similar to associativity, but between two different operators, and it only works if the multiplication is on the left...

Does this have a name or does it somehow follow from other properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is often called a $\,\color{#c00}{mixed}\,$ *associative law*, e.g. the common case of scalar multiplication

$$  c(x\cdot y)\, =\, (cx)\cdot y $$

Here the modifier $\,\color{#c00}{mix}\,$ signifies the associative combination of *different* operations.

Comment: In analogy to distributivity, could you say multiplication is left-mixed-associative over division?

Comment: @Patrick Yes, that is the language most commonly used for your example.

Answer (score 3):

It's associativity
$$a * (b/c)=a*(b*c^{-1})=(a*b)*c^{-1} = (a * b) / c$$

Comment: But the OP did not define $\ b/c \, =\, b c^{-1}.\ $ Presumably they ask about  general operations.